# Double linked list sorting by ascending order

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, insert, doubly-linked-list

I've been working for a school project and come across this issue.

I'm trying to store the list with malloc but this piece of code doesn't seem to work.

```
column_t *sorted_insert(column_t *lst, char col3[MAX_SIZE], long int rep){

if (!lst || rep < lst->rep)
{
    column_t *new = (column_t*) malloc(sizeof(column_t));
    strcpy(new->col3, col3);
    new->rep = rep;
    new->next = lst;
    new->previous = NULL;
    lst = new;
    if (lst->next)
        lst->next->previous = new;
}else
{
    lst->next = sorted_insert(lst->next,col3,rep);
    lst->next->previous = lst;
}

return lst;
}
```

Tried to call the function:

```
sorted_insert(lst,"Test",0);
printf("%s",lst->col3);
```

And as no output. The program just closes.

UPDATE @Vlad from Moscow

```
column_t *sorted_insert(column_t *lst, char col3[MAX_SIZE], long int rep){

if (lst == NULL|| rep < lst->rep)
{
    column_t *new = malloc(sizeof(column_t));

    if (new != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(new->col3, col3);
        new->rep = rep;
        new->previous = NULL;
        new->next = lst;
        if (lst != NULL)
            lst->previous = new;

    }

    lst = new;
}else
{

    column_t *new = sorted_insert(lst->next, col3, rep);
    if (new != NULL)
    {
        lst->next = new;
        new->previous = lst;
    }

}

return lst;
}
```

Changed the call to:

```
lst = sorted_insert(lst,tmp->col3,w);
display(lst);
```

Output:

[image]

Output of the list is correct now but not sorted by ascending order..

Comment: Shouldn't be an `&&` in the if rather then `||`?

Comment: "this piece of code doesn't seem to work" How so? What makes you think so? What did you try to debug? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Eraklon if the list is null or less than the value I think..

Comment: What is [the purpose of] `rep`? It doesn't change. How is it determined? Ordinarily, you'd insert based on `strcmp` between `col` and `lst->col` but you code seems to use `rep` as the in-sort criterion.

Comment: @CraigEstey If I want to add a node to my list I need to input one col3 and one rep. rep is being used to compare to the others already in the list since its a integer of how many times does "col3" exists.

Comment: Does Vlad's answer fix your problem? And, do you _have_ to have a recursive solution? It doesn't scale if you have a list with millions of elements (e.g. it would burn stack and probably cause a stack overflow). Also, I'm not sure how `rep` produces a sorted list based on the string if all strings are unique (e.g. `rep` is 1). You might need to do a dual key match (e.g. 1st on `rep` and then `col3` or vice versa)

Comment: It didn't. No I don't have specific terms, but in fact as you say it now this may scale... but not for millions. 
The reason of rep is to count how many col3 that I have. In another list I have col1, col2, col3 and col4. The exercice is to count how many col3 are there and group them. Example: col3: DA, DA, JI, FF, JD, FF. What Im trying to archive here is something like this: DA - 2 | JI - 1 | JD - 1 | FF - 2. I already figured out the first part now I just need them to be sorting by asceding order.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is in how you are calling the function.

The call should look like

```
column_t *lst = NULL;
lst = sorted_insert(lst,"Test",0);
```

Here is a simplified demonstrative program that uses your function `sorted_insert` with minor changes and excluding the data member of the character array type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node * sorted_insert( struct Node *head, int data )
{
    if ( head == NULL || data < head->data )
    {
        struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

        if ( new_node != NULL )
        {
            new_node->data = data;
            new_node->prev = NULL;
            new_node->next = head;
            if ( head != NULL ) head->prev = new_node;
        }

        head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        struct Node *new_node = sorted_insert( head->next, data );
        if ( new_node != NULL )
        {
            head->next = new_node;
            new_node->prev = head;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void display( struct Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    const size_t N = 10;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        head = sorted_insert( head, rand() % N );
        display( head );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
8 -> null
3 -> 8 -> null
3 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> 9 -> null
```

Comment: Updated it like yours but doesn't output correct... Il update on the post.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* Since it seems you're still having some trouble even with Vlad's answer, I've come up with a refactored version [that may or may not be what you wanted].

I'm using two lists. Append raw input strings to first list, but just bump the count if it's a dup of an existing list entry.

So, now we have a list that has the a single item for each unique string and its frequency/repetition count.

Then, *move* the entries into a second list, sorting by insertion based on the frequency.

So, here's the code. As I mentioned in my comments, the recursive solution doesn't scale, and, further, is slower. At the least, this may help you adapt your version. YMMV ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE    16

typedef struct column column_t;
struct column {
    column_t *next;
    column_t *prev;
    long rep;
    char col3[MAX_SIZE];
};

column_t *
newnode(char *col3)
{
    column_t *new = malloc(sizeof(column_t));

    strcpy(new->col3,col3);

    new->prev = NULL;
    new->next = NULL;

    new->rep = 1;

    return new;
}

// addnode -- add string to basic list
column_t *
addnode(column_t *head,char *col3)
{
    column_t *cur;
    column_t *prev;
    column_t *new;

    do {
        // add to empty list
        if (head == NULL) {
            new = newnode(col3);
            head = new;
            break;
        }

        // find matching node for string
        prev = NULL;
        for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
            if (strcmp(cur->col3,col3) == 0)
                break;
            prev = cur;
        }

        // increment count on existing node
        if (cur != NULL) {
            cur->rep += 1;
            break;
        }

        // append to tail of list
        new = newnode(col3);
        prev->next = new;
        new->prev = prev;
    } while (0);

    return head;
}

column_t *
sorted_insert(column_t *head,column_t *new)
{
    column_t *cur;
    column_t *prev;

    do {
        new->next = NULL;
        new->prev = NULL;

        // add to empty list
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = new;
            break;
        }

        // find next higher node count
        prev = NULL;
        for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
            if (cur->rep > new->rep)
                break;
            prev = cur;
        }

        // insert before a node that is higher
        if (cur != NULL) {
            prev = cur->prev;

            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->next = new;

            new->prev = prev;
            new->next = cur;

            // inserting before the head of the list
            if (cur == head)
                head = new;
            break;
        }

        // new node is higher than all -- append to tail of list
        new->prev = prev;
        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = new;
    } while (0);

    return head;
}

void
listprint(column_t *head,const char *tag)
{
    column_t *cur;

    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        printf("%s %s - %ld\n",tag,cur->col3,cur->rep);
}

int
main(void)
{
    column_t *orig = NULL;
    char *input[] = {
        "DA", "DA",
        "JL",
        "FF",
        "JD",
        "FF",
        "PQ", "QP",
        "QP", "QP", "QP",
        NULL
    };

    for (char **str = input;  *str != NULL;  ++str)
        orig = addnode(orig,*str);

    listprint(orig,"ORIG");

    column_t *sorted = NULL;
    column_t *next;
    for (;  orig != NULL;  orig = next) {
        next = orig->next;
        sorted = sorted_insert(sorted,orig);
    }

    listprint(sorted,"SORT");

    return 0;
}
```